# Using a subquery to rename columns

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a pattern in SQL queries that I've found myself repeating recently:

```
SELECT
    w,
    x,
    y,
    (w + x) / y as z
FROM
  (SELECT
      <some gigantic and complicated query> as w,
      a + b as x,
      a - b as y
   FROM
      basetable) somealias;
```

---

The issue is:

- a select query that does some complex operations, resulting in a column with a new name
- directly reusing the "new" column doesn't work in MySQL (unsure about other RDBMS's)

This code fails:

```
SELECT
    <some gigantic and complicated query> as w,
    a + b as x,
    a - b as y,
    (w + x) / y as z
FROM
    basetable;
```

Because MySQL doesn't allow column aliases (`x` and `y`) to be re-used in the same select query.

---

The solution I'm using:

- wrap the select in a subquery
- this renames the columns
- use the new column names from the outer query

I'm unsure whether it's a best practice, or a common practice, and thus easily understandable for other programmers.

Comment: Why not just `SELECT (a+b) / (a-b) AS z FROM basetable`?

Comment: @Kevin -- I've updated the question to also select `x` and `y` in the outer query.  Hopefully that clarifies the problem.

Comment: Ok. So am I reading your problem correctly, that you have to alias `x`, `y`, and `z`? That you can't add, say, `ORDER BY z`? (or `ORDER BY x` if you don't use the subquery?)  I believe you can `ORDER BY a+b`, if that's what you want.

Comment: @Kevin -- I've added the "desired" code, which fails.

Comment: Change `x / y` to `(a+b)/(a-b)` in the column spec. The alias can't be used there, but (from the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)) it "can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses."  Is the problem that `a+b` are actually more long/complex?  In that case you could [define a function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-function.html).

Comment: @Kevin -- yes, the problem is that the expressions for `x` and `y` could be arbitrarily complex, or even be subqueries.  I know there are other ways to solve this problem, I'm just trying to get a feel for how much of an anti-pattern this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your practice is fine. Here are the two queries and their explain results:

```
explain extended SELECT
    w,
    x,
    y,
    (w + x) / y as z
FROM
  (SELECT 
      (SELECT SUM(s) FROM test2) as w,
      a + b as x,
      a - b as y
   FROM
      test) somealias;
```

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 |       |
|  2 | DERIVED     | test       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 |       |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | test2      | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 |       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
```

```
explain extended SELECT 
      (SELECT SUM(s) FROM test2) as w,
      a + b as x,
      a - b as y,
      ((SELECT SUM(s) FROM test2) + (a + b)) / (a -b) as z
   FROM
      test
```

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | test  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 |       |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | test2 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 |       |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | test2 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |   100.00 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
```

If I'm right the second version runs the complex (maybe bottleneck) subquery on table `test2` *twice*, so it should be slower than the first query which runs the complex subquery only once. Furthermore, the first one is much easier to read. So, I prefer the first one. (I'm not a MySQL guru, feel free to correct me.)

Answer (score 3):

As long as the variables are well-named, I think your way (subquery) will be clear and therefore quite acceptable, though I'm not quite sure whether it will affect performance or to what extent (try benchmarking).

That said, I'd still urge you to use a [prepared query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)  or [stored procedure or function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines-syntax.html), I think that would make it even more clear, and potentially faster.